# UPDATE with SQL Cursor

Tags: sql, postgresql, cursor, psql

I need help with my sql script.

Inventory is a table which contains orderunit, location, siteid and itemnum. This update aims to change all "orderunit = NULL" by the same item (itemnum) in such a way :

```
%_TAB => %_TD
```

and

```
%_TD => %_ACM
```

I want the same result with cursors :

```
UPDATE INVENTORY A 
SET A.orderunit = (SELECT B.orderunit 
                   FROM INVENTORY B 
                   WHERE B.location = A.siteid || '_TD' 
                     AND B.itemnum = A.itemnum) 
WHERE A.location = A.siteid || '_TAB' 
  AND A.orderunit IS NULL;

UPDATE INVENTORY A 
SET A.orderunit = (SELECT B.orderunit 
                   FROM INVENTORY B 
                   WHERE B.location = A.siteid || '_ACM' 
                     AND B.itemnum = A.itemnum) 
WHERE A.location = A.siteid || '_TD' 
  AND A.orderunit IS NULL;
```

I tried to make this and it seems not to work.

```
DECLARE
    inv_itemnum INVENTORY.itemnum%TYPE
    inv_location INVENTORY.location%TYPE
    inv_siteid INVENTORY.siteid%TYPE
    inv_orderunit INVENTORY.orderunit%TYPE

    CURSOR c_inventory_tab IS
        SELECT orderunit FROM INVENTORY WHERE location = siteid || '_TAB' AND orderunit IS NULL
        FOR UPDATE;
    CURSOR c_inventory_td IS
        SELECT orderunit FROM INVENTORY WHERE location = siteid || '_TD' AND orderunit IS NULL
        FOR UPDATE;
    CURSOR c_inventory_tabB
        SELECT orderunit FROM INVENTORY WHERE location = siteid || '_TD' AND itemnum = itemnum;
    CURSOR c_inventory_tdB
        SELECT orderunit FROM INVENTORY WHERE location = siteid || '_ACM' AND itemnum = itemnum;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN c_inventory_tab
    LOOP
    UPDATE INVENTORY
    SET orderunit = c_inventory_tabB;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is there a reason to switch to cursors? RDBMS Updates using set based processing are typically far more efficient. Is this just a learning exercise or do you expect a performance gain?  which can happen [link](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/set-based-vs-cursor-based-solutions-running-aggregates)

Comment: It is a learning exercise

Comment: You need to say `UPDATE ... WHERE CURRENT OF c_inventory_tab`. You also need to move the `c_inventory_tabB` cursor yourself using `FETCH` commands, until both cursors are pointing at the same `itemnum`. You can do this _much_ more efficiently if your query results are sorted.